# init root viewcontroller causes crash

Tags: ios, ios6

I used codes below to init a root view controller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 

{

[window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: rootViewController  ];
}
```

it worked well on ios 4 about 2 years,ios5 1 years, there is no any problem when start to run the app 
but on ios6 it crashed and reported

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller  as a child of view controller:'

Welcome any comment

Comment: Is your rootViewController already a child of an other viewController ? or is it rootViewController on a window ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'rootViewController' is already in your view hierarchy. Remove it from whatever other container its in (window.rootViewController ?) first (window.rootViewController = nil).

Comment: Somewhat related question: is calling UINavigationController-init legal, or do I have to call -initWithRootViewController:?  If the latter, is it legal to pass nil?

Comment: Apple says the preferred initializer should be preferred. However one can imagine that it just sets the root controller, so it will probably be ok to use the 'initWithFrame' method then set the property. But then ask yourself why do that? When you stray from the lines you increase the likelihood of future problems. My app got bit twice by iOS6 due to minor straying. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are adding rootViewController's view to window then immediately trying to add rootViewController's view to the new UINavigationController. Instead try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...    

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [window addSubview:nav.view];

    ...
}
```

or even better:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ...    

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    window.rootViewController = nav;

    ...
}
```

The ... are there to show that these are incomplete examples of `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. You need to make sure you have included creating your UIWindow and calling `-makeKeyAndVisible` on it.